# URL encoding in java does not work for me

Tags: java, url, attributes, request, encode

i set `Leave ApplicationForm` in HTTP Request attribute and i get the value like the below

```
String parameterValue = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute(request.getParameter(parameterName));
```

after encoding the value also i get the following value which is wrong :

```
Leave&#x20;ApplicationForm
```

I have to remove the extra characters  and pass only the needed one, in this case it is `Leave ApplicationFrom`

I tried with this also

```
URLEncoder.encode(requestAttributeValue, "UTF-8")
```

but still i get the same value with some junk characters.

Please help me to resolve this.

thanks

Comment: I get `Leave+ApplicationForm` with your second example and the `String` "Leave ApplicationForm"

Comment: How is "Leave&#x20;ApplicationForm" wrong? `&#x20;` is the hex value for 'space'.

Comment: I need to get only Leave ApplicationForm, how do i?

Comment: URLEncoder.encode,  converts the String to url format, guess you want the contrary.